# CSS error caused by strange closing of divs

Tags: css

I've encountered a pretty weird CSS error which stops CSS from properly being applied. Check out the screenshot I took from the Chrome inspection tool.

[Weird CSS in inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPJ8F.png)

The code is pretty straightforward:

```
<div class="addownsong">
<span class="hidesongadder"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
<h4>Artiest</h4>
<input id="artist-name" type="text" style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABHklEQVQ4EaVTO26DQBD1ohQWaS2lg9JybZ+AK7hNwx2oIoVf4UPQ0Lj1FdKktevIpel8AKNUkDcWMxpgSaIEaTVv3sx7uztiTdu2s/98DywOw3Dued4Who/M2aIx5lZV1aEsy0+qiwHELyi+Ytl0PQ69SxAxkWIA4RMRTdNsKE59juMcuZd6xIAFeZ6fGCdJ8kY4y7KAuTRNGd7jyEBXsdOPE3a0QGPsniOnnYMO67LgSQN9T41F2QGrQRRFCwyzoIF2qyBuKKbcOgPXdVeY9rMWgNsjf9ccYesJhk3f5dYT1HX9gR0LLQR30TnjkUEcx2uIuS4RnI+aj6sJR0AM8AaumPaM/rRehyWhXqbFAA9kh3/8/NvHxAYGAsZ/il8IalkCLBfNVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; cursor: auto;">

<h4>Titel</h4>
<input id="track-name" type="text">

<div class="minutes">
    <h4>Minuten</h4>
    <input id="track-minutes" type="text" min="0" max="59">
</div>

<div class="timedivider">
    <h4>:</h4>
</div>

<div class="seconds">
    <h4>Seconden</h4>
    <input id="track-seconds" type="text" min="0" max="59">
</div>

<p><strong>Wil je een scanbare Spotify code toevoegen aan je topplaatje? Gebruik onderstaande zoekbalk om het juiste nummer te vinden!</strong></p>
<input style="text-align: center;border-color:#df0d84" id="songsearch2" type="text" placeholder="Vind je favoriete nummer op basis van titel">
<div id="songsearch2-results"></div>
<div id="selected-spotify-code"></div>
<input hidden="" id="uploaded-image">
<div class="dropzone dropzonebox dz-clickable" id="my-awesome-dropzone"><div class="dz-message" data-dz-message=""><span>Sleep een foto hierheen of klik om te uploaden</span></div></div>
<div style="color:#ff0000;margin-top:10px;"><center><strong>Let op: voor het beste resultaat, voeg je een vierkante foto toe</strong></center></div>
<div style="background-color:#ddd;color:#545454;border-color:#ddd;" class="createButton placeholderButton">Voeg eerst alle gegevens toe</div>
<div style="display: none;" class="createButton addCreation">Voeg je creatie toe!</div>
</div>
```

I tried uncovering closing/opening errors for divs, but they're all properly showing. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you run the HTML through a validator?

Comment: The code you have shown so far, does not appear to reproduce this: https://jsfiddle.net/q9ztgh7r/ I’m guessing, you probably have this code repeated multiple times? Is it generated in a loop, or did you manually copy&paste it several times? Anyway, as @Mitya already suggested, validating your HTML should help find what’s wrong: https://validator.w3.org/nu/